# How to get the new position of a moving shape in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I create some ellipses some seconds after my program is started like this    `Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse();` then I move the ellipses like this

```
public void MoveTo(Shape target, double newX, double newY, double oldX, double oldY)
        {

            TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
            target.RenderTransform = trans;
            DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(0, newY - oldY, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation(0, newX - oldX, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim1);
            trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim2);

        }
```

when they are within their movement to the new position I want to get their new X and Y position while moving  , I use a timer to get their X and Y on the time I want but when I use `Canvas.GetLeft(name)` it returns Nan and I used `Point p = mEllipse.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), canvasName);` and this returns the initial position of the ellipse not the new one

Comment: You could use Canvas.GetLeft and Canvas.GetTop if you would animate the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties instead of the X and Y properties of a TranslateTransform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always get the current position of the child of a Canvas by calling `Canvas.GetLeft` and `Canvas.GetTop` if you animate the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties like this:

```
public static void MoveTo(UIElement target, double x, double y)
{
    var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    target.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, new DoubleAnimation(x, duration));
    target.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, new DoubleAnimation(y, duration));
}
```

Note that you would also have to set initial values for the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties, like

```
Canvas.SetLeft(myEllipse, 0);
Canvas.SetTop(myEllipse, 0);
```